# Can't click any button on the UI of android studio

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio

I used to install Android Studio on Ubuntu14.04 and it worded well. Now I install it on Ubuntu12.04 but have a strange problem. Sometimes when I run it, it seems fine, but I can't click any buttons on it. I can use the mouse to highlight the button, but I can't click on it to make some action. Like open the SDK manager, create a New Project, etc. The only way I can is to use the "ENTER" button to take the place of left click. It's very weird and inconvenient.

Does any one have an idea about it? Thank you very much!

===============================================================

Now it again becomes out of control. In the terminal it shows:
In the terminal it shows:

Received result DaemonCommandResult[type=Success, value=org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildActionResult@3ce49329] from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=3808, address=[b7a9bbfd-4a65-4ef0-9dce-d6afb9d0f860 port:34032, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1, /127.0.0.1]], idle=true, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=3585f0de-2fbe-4575-a856-bca78b93ea4b,javaHome=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_75,daemonRegistryDir=/home/faye/.gradle/daemon,pid=3808,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]}.

Comment: Do you get any errors? or any logs?

Comment: I just added some information shows in the terminal. Is it related to this bug?

Comment: I'm actually seeing this on Windows 7 right now -- all hover actions are responsive, keyboard input works, but left/right mouse clicks don't do anything

Answer (score 7):

I haven't conclusively proved this yet, but my theory is Android Studio breaks if you ever have more than one pointing device attached (not sure if Android Studio has to be open while they're both attached).

Yesterday, I swapped mice (unplugging the old and then plugging in the new).  Android Studio was fine.  Today, I plugged in the old and then unplugged the new.  That's when I noticed the described behavior.  No amount of unplugging, re-plugging, or restarting Android Studio helped.  I restarted the machine with both mice attached and it was still broken.

Strangely, it even affected the Beta version of Android Studio that wasn't even open while all of this was happening.  I even installed an update to the Beta version (using the keyboard); still no mouse clicks.

I finally restarted my machine with only one mouse attached.  Android Studio is back to normal.

Comment: I'll plug in a second mouse the next time I have time to deal with it.  If Android Studio stops responding to clicks, that should prove it pretty conclusively.

Comment: Restarting the machine fixed it for me. (Using Synergy, so I guess I do have an additional virtual pointing device)

Comment: I had a mouse plugged in, and neither it nor my trackpad could click buttons in the AVD Manager. Unplugged my mouse, and suddenly my trackpad worked.

Comment: "I haven't conclusively proved this yet, but my theory is " -- This is a GREAT observation. As touch-screen laptops essentially have TWO mice systems under Linux. As the cursor can be positioned by touching the LCD screen or by using the normal touchpad (mouse) to position the cursor.  So, it is as if two mice were plugged into the system.

This problem seems to impact more than just Android Studio, the entire family of IntelliJ editors: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000577850-Intellij-IDE-caret-following-cursor